# Edits hosts file ignored by chrome

Tags: dns, hosts

I'm trying to cut down on procrastination in a fun way (read hacking) by rooting my phone (moto g2) and editing the `/system/etc/hosts` file like this

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
::1           ip6-localhost
127.0.0.1     youtube.com
(trailing newline)
```

I tried the following fixes:

- Turning off Data Saver
- Clear all data in Settings->Storage->Apps
- Clear cache from chrome://net-internals/#dns and clear
- Reboot

Still I'm perfectly able to access www.youtube.com, no problemo. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect `www.youtube.com` to 127.0.0.1 you have to add it exactly that way to your hosts files.

However you only redirected the main domain `youtube.com` to 127.0.0.1. not the subdomain `www.youtube.com`. Note that this does not affect subdomains. If you want to cut of Youtube completely you have to add every subdomain to your hosts file.

Comment: Chrome is still ignoring the hosts file while other browsers abide by it (eg Opera).